# Prove or Disprove: If $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}:\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0$,then $f(x)$ is odd.

Tags: calculus, integration

## Problem

Prove or Disprove: Suppose $f(x)$ is continuous. If $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0(\forall a \in \mathbb{R})$,then $f(x)$ is odd.

## Comment

Obviously, its converse version holds. But how is itself?

Comment: I think you need continuity too.

Comment: This is false, because you can change the value at one point without affecting integrability or the value of the integral.

Comment: @user10354138u yes！Now, assume $f(x)$ is continous!

Answer (score 10):

Let $g(x):=f(x)+f(-x)$ so $0=\int_0^a g(x)dx$ for all $a$. If $g$ is continuous, we may differentiate to get $g(a)=0$ so $f$ is odd.

Comment: In fact, you can differentiate $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\,dx$ directly to get $f(a)+f(-a)$.

Comment: @preferred_anon Doing that works fine if $f$ is continuous; what I'm doing only requires $g$'s continuity.

Comment: Ok, fair enough!

Answer (score 2):

$I = \int^a_{-a} f(x)dx = \int^0_{-a} f(x)dx + \int^a_{0} f(x)dx$

Let in the first integral $x+a = u   \implies dx =du$

> $I = \int^a_{0} f(a+u)du + \int^a_{0} f(x)dx$

As, $\int^b_ag(x)dx = \int^b_ag(a+b-x)dx$

$I = \int^a_{0} f( a- (a+u))du+ \int^a_{0} f(x)dx = \int^{a}_0f(-u)du + \int^a_{0} f(x)dx$

Substitute $u =x$

$I = \int^{a}_0f(-x)dx + \int^a_{0} f(x)dx = 0$

$\int^a_{0} f(-x)dx = -\int^{a}_0f(x)dx$

> $$f(-x) = -f(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

There are already many good answers but here's perhaps yet another way to think about it:

You can take away an arbitrary large "middle-part" from the integral, since that is $0$, too. And you are left with two tiny slices in the ends. Let those slices go to zero and the values tend to the values of the function (you might have to make a change of variable in one of those).

Answer (score 1):

> A function $f(x)$ is said to be odd function if $f(-x)=-f(x)$

Now  $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$

$$I=\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx=0\implies\int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx + \int_{0}^a f(x)dx = 0 \implies I_1 + I_2 =0$$ where $I_1 = \int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx$ and $I_2 = \int_{0}^a f(x)dx$

Let, $t = – x$ or $x = – t$, so that $dt = – dx$

Also, observe that when $x = – a$, $t = a$, and when $x = 0, t = 0$

Then $I_1= \int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx=-\int_{a}^0 f(-t)dt=\int_{0}^{a}f(-t) dt=\int_{0}^{a}f(-x) dx$

Now $$I=I_1 + I_2 =0\implies \int_{-a}^0 f(x)dx + \int_{0}^a f(x)dx = 0 \implies \int_{0}^{a}f(-x) dx + \int_{0}^a f(x)dx = 0 \implies \int_{0}^{a}(f(-x)+f(x)) dx=0$$ which is only possible if $f(-x)+f(x)=0\implies f(-x)=-f(x)$ i.e., if $f(x)$ is an odd function.